# Custom Prometheus metrics not queryable

Tags: prometheus, promql

I've got Prometheus running on a bare metal Ubuntu server, no Kubernetes or Docker. I want to monitor a custom hardware BrightSign Player (BSP) via their plugin extensibility solution. I've got the BSP endpoint returning what I believe to be a valid OpenMetrics, though I'm happy to be wrong if this is my problem.

[image: Custom metrics response]

The Targets screen in the Prometheus UI reports that the endpoint is up and I believe the syntax is correct because while developing when I *did* have a syntax error, there was a relevant error message on this page.

[image: Targets Looking OK]

When I search for either of these metrics nothing is returned

[image: No metrics]

This is the relevant bit of prometheus.yml

```
- job_name: 'bsp-001'
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['10.1.5.21:8081']
```

Is there something else necessary for custom metrics to be queryable in Prometheus? I'm brand new to this tool so don't assume I didn't miss something obvious. Thank you!

Comment: Did you have a look into the prometheus logs? There are imortant hints too for such issues.

Comment: I'm running this via systemctl. Should I look in those logs? I checked the tail and don't see anything obvious but I may be missing something. Would these hints be present at app startup or when attempting to scrape my endpoint? Either way I can simplify the yml config and isolate to just this one Target.